# Objective-C: message syntax vs. dot syntax; what's the difference?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, syntactic-sugar

If I'm using `@synthesize foo;`, what's the difference between the following:

```
// message syntax
[myObj setFoo:5];
[myObj foo];
```

and

```
// dot syntax
myObj.foo = 5;
myObj.foo;
```

I like the consistency of the dot syntax but I don't know if it's doing something I should be I concerned about.

Any additional information would be a great help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no functional difference between using dot syntax and using message syntax.

I find that using message syntax is more consistent with the language as a whole and that dot syntax was just implemented as a convenience to programmers who were coming over from languages that used it (Java comes to mind).

All I ask is: Whichever one you choose, be consistent with it. **Do not mix and match single property setters**! (Multiple-argument setters are obviously exempt).

Comment: agreed.  Stick with one or the other.  I prefer to use dot syntax because it tells me that I'm doing something which will likely retain or copy an object.

Comment: I second that! But I also (try) to use the dot notation so I can see at a glance when the member is defined as a property vs. a method.

Comment: "Do not mix and match" is kind of pointless. If you use dot notation for setting all your properties and then have to add a setter which takes two arguments, what do you do?

Comment: @w.m Then you have no choice but to mix and match. This is strictly for setting single properties - this does not apply to multiple argument setters.

Comment: I think dot syntax was a big mistake.  It pollutes the syntax and confuses people.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same.

The dot syntax is used to signify the access of `@property`'s which you can also acces via:

```
[myObject setValue: [NSNumber numberWithIntValue:5] forKey:@"foo"];
[myObject valueForKey:@"foo"];
```

But in essence the calls are the same.