# iOS NSDictionary Copy Memory Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I have two issues, I have one method that builds a dictionary, I then save that to a global variable that I have synthesized. If I just assign it, when I try to access it from another method, its empty, if I use copy, it leaks memory.

I can just assign it and it works if its, lets say, a "simpler" object like a NSString, why doesnt this work with NSDictionary?.

.h:

```
@interface ClassIHate : UIViewController{
 NSDictionary *postBuild;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *postBuild;
-(void)prepData;
@end
```

I´m only including the classes that use the variable postBuild, as that is my issue.
.m

```
@implementation ClassIHate
@synthesize postBuild;

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 postBuild = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
 [postBuild release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)prepData{
    NSInteger i = 0;
 NSMutableDictionary *_postBuild = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
 for (NSString *key in self.keys) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [ops valueForKey:key];
     NSInteger j = 0;
        for (MyDataType *object in array) {
   NSString *abc = object.abc;
   UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i]];
   UITextView *tv = (UITextView *)cell.accessoryView;
   NSString *mon = tv.text;
   NSString *monFormat = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf",[mon doubleValue]]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@","];
   [_postBuild setObject:monFormat forKey:abc];
   j++;
        }
  i++;
    }
 //postBuild = _postBuild; //Empty when called in other method
        postBuild =  [_postBuild copy]; //Leaks memory
 [_postBuild release];
}

-(void)realizarOperaciones{
 //DO STUFF
 NSArray *postKeys = [postBuild allKeys]; //postBuild is nil if I dont use copy, leaks memory if I do.
        //DO STUFF
}
```

What could be the issue here?
Thanks, Stefano.

Comment: It's an instance variable, not a global variable. It's also not a synthesized variable; only the method definitions are synthesized in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
postBuild =  [_postBuild copy]; //Leaks memory
[_postBuild release];
```

Should be this:

```
[self setPostBuild:_postBuild];
[_postBuild release];
```

You need to call the synthesized setter method ([however way you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259946/objective-c-message-syntax-vs-dot-syntax-whats-the-difference/4259975#4259975)) for this to work and to keep the `retainCount` at `1`.

Comment: Wow, that was retarded of me, thanks a lot, I cant belive I didnt notice that.

Comment: Here's why: the first one leaks your *old* postBuild object, as you don't release it - as the setter does automatically per declaration.

Comment: This is the wrong answer.  In fact, the original fragment of code does not leak.

Comment: Sorry it's not wrong as paulbailey pointed out but it's not completely right either.

Answer (score 2):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but it is not completely correct.

```
postBuild =  [_postBuild copy]; //Leaks memory
[_postBuild release];
```

is actually OK if you only call the method once. To stop it from leaking on second and subsequent calls to `prepData` you'll need to release postBuild first or use Jacob's rewrite.  postBuild is set to a copy of _postBuild that you own and _postBuild is then correctly released.

There is also a leak caused by this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
 postBuild = nil;
}
```

Remember that you own postBuild but you have just set it to nil without releasing it.  You need to do this instead:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setPostBuild: nil];
}
```

Comment: I think it does leak. What would happen if `prepData` was called more than once? I would think that `postBuild` should at least be released before the copy. As you point out `viewDidUnload` also leaks.

Comment: I decided not to copy, I instead used self.postBuild = _postBuild, in view did unload im doing self.postBuild = nil; that would be equivalent to what you said, right?

Comment: @blindstuff: Yes, that's fine.