# Is dot syntax or bracket syntax correct for property access?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, properties

Suppose I have

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

Later on in another class `B`, I want to access that array, to check how many items are in it. I can do one of two things in `B` (`a` is an instance of `A`):

Option 1

```
[a.array count]
```

Option 2

```
[[a array] count];
```

Which option is the best way to do this? Is option 2 the right way to access the array when using `[a array]` as the getter method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: message syntax vs. dot syntax; what's the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259946/objective-c-message-syntax-vs-dot-syntax-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both are the same if you have synthesized the array. in first one you just call the property and in 2nd one you are calling the getter method which was generated by @synthesize action.

and sure the 2nd option is the right way as @synthesize makes two methods

1- getter that is same as the property name
2- setter that is add set with property name at start with first letter captial like setArray.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two if you have synthesized the array, as The Saad said. However, I recommend bracket syntax as to remain consistent in all your method calling as all other Objective-C methods (aside from functions from C) use bracket syntax to be called.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference until you decide to rename the generated getter/setter methods and the message is likely to become invalid.

For the public instance variables you can skip the accessor methods (both property and method styles) and use the structure dereference operator:

```
@interface A : NSObject
{
   NSMutableArray *array;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

classA.m

```
[self->array count];
```

classB.m

```
[a->array count];
```

Doing this, you waive the convenience of both operation and memory management optimizations which you have using properties (in both access styles) with the different attributes, see [more](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103).

As example for the NSString property

```
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *sVar;
```

the generated setter looks like this:

```
-(void)setSVar:(NSString*)inSVar
{
        if (self->sVar != inSVar)
        {
                [self->sVar release];
                self->sVar = [inSVar copy];
        }
}
```